# Keeping two sets of files for web design projects

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

In undertaking web site design/programming projects, I was wondering if it is common for the gurus to keep two sets of files. One for development, and one for production as in jQuery.

The reason is that I have a project which has the Markup & CSS very heavily commented by me. Also the code is indented, spaced and tabbed. For example

**Mark Up**

```
<!-- START google translate script link ================================================================== -->
<meta name="google-translate-customization" content="9f841e7780177523-3214ceb76f765f38-gc38c6fe6f9d06436-c"></meta>
<!-- END google translate script link ==================================================================== -->

<!-- START stylesheet link =============================================================================== -->
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!-- END stylesheet link ================================================================================= -->

<div id="header_text"><!-- START header_text ============================================================= -->
<h1 id="first-child">Pak United Food Services Ltd.,</h1>
<h1 id="last-child"><a href="http://www.pufs.org/" title="www.pufs.org">PUFS</a></h1>
<span></span>
</div><!-- END header_text =============================================================================== -->
```

**CSS**

```
/* START import ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@import url("reset.css");
@import url("feature-carousel.css");
/* END import --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

/* START wrapper ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
div#wrapper
{
width: 100%;
font-family: Calibri, Arial, Georgia,Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 22px;
background: url("../images/bg.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 #1D2426;
}
/* END wrapper -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

And so on. Surely I should not use these files for deployment. Ideally they should be trimmed with all the comments, spaces, indents, tabs, (even EOL's?) removed. But once that is done the code will be very unfriendly to read.

So should we have than two file sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very very bad idea to have two sets of files. Sooner or later you will make a mistake and one will be out of step with the other.

Why not have a deployment procedure? Part of that procedure could be taking a snapshot of the files and running a script over those files to before deployment to remove spaces etc.

Comment: You lost me. After the deployment, will we not have another set of file?

Comment: The deployed files would be transformed, as in removed comments, minified etc. Depends on what you do with your deploy procedure. Personally I use filters to remove/strip the response for whitespaces, comments and such.

Comment: @Jawad - Inthe deployment process you take a copy of the files, remove the spaces etc. Upload them to the web site then throw the files that you copied in this process. Next time around you repeat the process. i.e. You only have one set of files for development.

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

Most people use a build script, either hand rolled, or something like http://gruntjs.com/

Personally, I do a few things:

- A script concatentates and minify javascript using uglify.js
- SASS ensures my CSS is free of comments and minified
- A script uses jpegtrans/optipng/pngcrush etc ensure images are small
- A PHP output filter caches my PHP and minifies it on the way

That means that I can just make a site however I like, but am sure that the user will see 1 CSS file, 1 JS file, some minified HTML, and small images.